# Why is my function not returning the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

This is my code:

```
document.getElementById('revealUser').onclick = displayDaUsers

function displayDaUsers(){
  pullAllUsersFromDB();
  debugger;
}


function pullAllUsersFromDB(){
  rootRef.child('users').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var users_array = [];
    var users_object = snapshot.val();
    Object.keys(users_object).map(function(key) {
      users_array.push(users_object[key]);
    });
    // window.dateApp.allUsers = users_array;
    return users_array
  });
}
```

html:

```
<input type="submit" id="revealUser" value="reveal user">
```

I put a debugger in to see the problem but it does not help. When I go into the console and type in `users_array`
I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: users_array is not defined(…)`

NEW CODE (EDIT):

according to another stackoverflow answers this should work..

```
function displayDaUsers(){
  var test = pullAllUsersFromDB();
  console.log(test);
  //pullAllUsersFromDB();
  //debugger;
  //setUpFirstUser()
}


function pullAllUsersFromDB(){
  rootRef.child('users').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var users_array = [];
    var users_object = snapshot.val();
    Object.keys(users_object).map(function(key) {
      users_array.push(users_object[key]);
    });
    //window.dateApp.allUsers = users_array;
    return users_array
  });
}
```

Comment: it's declared inside a function (local scope). so it's not accessible from console

Comment: `users_array` is a local variable, and you never catch the return value of the function call.

Comment: but I put a debugger in, which means I have access inside that function? @FastSnail

Comment: @Waterman1 yes of course

Comment: so why is not accessible or rather, how can I make it accessible?

Comment: @FastSnail edited

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès edited

Answer (score 0):

The return value `users_array` is local to the scope of the anonymous callback function `function(snapshot) {...`. In other words, its value is lost outside of that scope.

At what point in your logic do you need access to `user_array`? If you need access to it outside of the context of your functions, maybe it makes sense to define a variable with greater scope, and then setting its value in your anonymous function. E.g.

```
document.getElementById...
var arr;

...

function pullAllUsersFromDB() {
    ...
    ...function(snapshot) {
        arr = users_array;
    });
}

// pullAllUsersFromDB() (and its callback) must be called for arr to be defined at this point in execution
```

Comment: I need it to be accessible to the other method `displayDaUsers`. is that not possible?

Comment: If that is the case then it makes sense to pass in `users_array` as a callback value that `displayDaUsers` can access. So, `pullAllUsersFromDB` should be augmented with a callback parameter.

Comment: so how would that look? what argument would `pullAllUsersFromDB` take and what would it look like inside the other function? (i'm not asking you to do it for me, just need to learn how this type of scoping works)

Comment: edited now dude

Comment: Please see the answers to the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call